# Can I use data from an api saved in one object method in another... javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, object, methods

I'm wondering if anyone could help me find a way to use data pulled from an api and stored as a property in one method into another. This is kinda what I'm looking at atm (not the full code but everything that's relevant), I want to use the data saved in the channel method in the populate method. Thank you for any help, I hope that's an obvious enough explanation. :)

- Fixed :D but I don't think I can answer because the question was apparently a duplicate *

  ```
  var viewer = {

      init: function () {

          var i;

          this.url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/";

          for (i = 0; i < userArray.length; i += 1) {

              this.callAPI(userArray[i]);

          }
      },

      callAPI: function (users) {

          var firstCall = $.get(this.url + "channels/" + users, "jsonp");
          var secondCall = $.get(this.url + "streams/" + users, "jsonp");

          $.when(firstCall, secondCall).done(this.userData).then(this.populate);

      },

      userData: function (data, get) {

          if (data[0].logo === null) {
              this.avatar = "<img class=\"logo\" src=\"http://via.placeholder.com/50x50\" />";
          } else {
              this.avatar = "<img class=\"logo\" src=\"" + data[0].logo + "\" />";
          }

          if (get[0].stream === null || get[0].stream.isUndefined) {

              this.status = "Offline"

          } else {

              this.status = get[0].stream.channel.status;
          }

          this.displayName = data[0].display_name;

      },

      populate: function () {

          var list = new List();

          list.add(new User(this.avatar, this.displayName, this.status));

          list.draw(getWrapper);

      }

  };

  viewer.init();
  ```

  }());

Comment: You can declare a global variable then assign the `data` value to it in the `channel` method. After that you can access that global variable in your `populate` method

Comment: Cheers for the reply, it still doesn't work outside of channel though :/ does it make a difference that all of the code is wrapped in a self executing function?

Comment: You've fallen into the classic mistake of async programming. The linked duplicate should explain all your options.

Comment: Cheers :) There's already a callback function running, and I can already retrieve the data from the API I just need to be able to save and share that data from "Channel" to "Populate"

Answer (score -1):

Declare one global variable. assign the value from one function and you can able access from another like below.

```
var GlobalVar;

function Fn1()
{
GlobalVar="test";
}

function Fn1()
{
alert(GlobalVar);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, possibly because all of the code is wrapped in a self executing function with it being object orientated.

Comment: @DannyPearson I hope it will work if you made like below. i have given some sample to use global variable.  var GlobalVar; var viewer = {init: function (p) {GlobalVar=p},init2: function () {alert(GlobalVar);}

Answer (score -1):

```
var viewer = {

    init: function () {

        var holdData;
        var i;

        this.url = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/";

        for (i = 0; i < userArray.length; i += 1) {

            this.callAPI(userArray[i]);

            this.populate();
        }
    },

    callAPI: function (users) {

        $.get(this.url + "channels/" + users, this.channel, "jsonp");
        $.get(this.url + "streams/" + users, this.isOnline, "jsonp");

    },

    channel: function (data) {

        if (data.logo === null) {
            this.avatar = "<img class=\"logo\" src=\"http://via.placeholder.com/50x50\" />";
        } else {
            this.avatar = "<img class=\"logo\" src=\"" + data.logo + "\" />";
        }

        this.displayName = data.display_name;
        holdData = data;

    },

    isOnline: function () {


    },

    populate: function () {
        //here you can access the variable holdData

        var list = new List();

        list.add(new User(this.avatar, this.displayName, "placeholder"));

        list.draw(getWrapper);

    }

};

viewer.init();
```

Comment: Not only will this not solve the problem, but `holdData` isnt even in scope within merthod `channel`